# Best way to prove all 3 solutions for exponential equation?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I was given the equation;

$(x-7)^a=1$

where $a=(x-4)$

The 3 solutions are:
$x=4, 6, 8$

When $x=4$,

$(-3)^0=1$, which can be reached by setting $(x-4)=0$ because $n^0=1$

When $x=8$,

$1^4=1$, which can be reached by setting $(x-7)=1$ because $1^n=1$

The less obvious one and the one I was not able to reach algebraically but rather just noticed was $x=6$, which produces;

$(-1)^2=1$, because $(-1)^n=1$ such that n is an even integer

How could I reach $x=6$ algebraically?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you see it. I would consider $x-4=0$, as you wrote, but then $|x-7|=1$ as a necessary (but not sufficient) condition if the exponent is non-zero. Then $x-7=1\iff x=6$ and $-(x-7)=1\iff x=8$ should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well since we have $1$ at the RHS, then we have three possible ways achieve it using exponentials. First is to set the exponent to $0$, so we have:

$$x-4 = 0 \implies x=4$$

Second is to set the base to $1$, since $1^k = 1; \forall k$

$$x-7 = 1 \implies x=8$$

The third is to set the base to $-1$, since $(-1)^{2n} = 1; \forall n$

$$x-7 = -1 \implies x=6$$

Now since $6$ is an odd number, we get that it's a solution.